# Close the polyhedron

Tags: graphics3d

I would like to close this polyhedron, forming its 3D graphics, I'm using rotate but I can't rotate the faces as I want. Help

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{{Polygon[{{0.`, 2.8660254037844384`, 
       0}, {0.8660254037844386`, 2.3660254037844384`, 
       0}, {0.8660254037844386`, 3.3660254037844384`, 0}}], 
    Rotate[Polygon[{{0.8660254037844386`, 3.3660254037844384`, 
        0}, {0.8660254037844386`, 2.3660254037844384`, 
        0}, {1.8660254037844386`, 2.3660254037844384`, 
        0}, {1.8660254037844386`, 3.3660254037844384`, 0}}], 
     a, {1.8660254037844386`, 3.3660254037844384`, 0.7}], 
    Rotate[Polygon[{{1.8660254037844386`, 3.3660254037844384`, 
        0}, {1.8660254037844386`, 2.3660254037844384`, 
        0}, {2.732050807568877`, 2.8660254037844384`, 0}}], 
     a, {1.8660254037844386`, 3.3660254037844384`, 0.7}], 
    Rotate[Polygon[{{0.8660254037844386`, 2.3660254037844384`, 
        0}, {1.3660254037844386`, 1.5`, 0}, {1.8660254037844386`, 
        2.3660254037844384`, 0}}], 
     a, {{1.8660254037844386`, 3.3660254037844384`, 
       1}, {1.8660254037844386`, 2.3660254037844384`, 1}}], 
    Polygon[{{0.`, 1.8660254037844386`, 0}, {0.5`, 1.`, 
       0}, {1.3660254037844386`, 1.5`, 0}, {0.8660254037844386`, 
       2.3660254037844384`, 0}}], 
    Polygon[{{1.8660254037844386`, 2.3660254037844384`, 
       0}, {1.3660254037844386`, 1.5`, 0}, {2.232050807568877`, 1.`, 
       0}, {2.732050807568877`, 1.8660254037844386`, 0}}], 
    Polygon[{{2.732050807568877`, 1.8660254037844386`, 
       0}, {2.232050807568877`, 1.`, 0}, {3.232050807568877`, 1.`, 
       0}}], Polygon[{{1.3660254037844386`, 0.5`, 
       0}, {2.232050807568877`, 0.`, 0}, {2.232050807568877`, 1.`, 
       0}}], Polygon[{{2.232050807568877`, 1.`, 
       0}, {2.232050807568877`, 0.`, 0}, {3.232050807568877`, 0.`, 
       0}, {3.232050807568877`, 1.`, 0}}], 
    Polygon[{{3.232050807568877`, 1.`, 0}, {3.232050807568877`, 0.`, 
       0}, {4.098076211353316`, 0.5`, 0}}], 
    Polygon[{{2.732050807568877`, 1.8660254037844386`, 
       0}, {3.232050807568877`, 1.`, 0}, {4.098076211353316`, 1.5`, 
       0}, {3.598076211353316`, 2.3660254037844384`, 0}}], 
    Polygon[{{3.598076211353316`, 2.3660254037844384`, 
       0}, {4.098076211353316`, 1.5`, 0}, {4.598076211353316`, 
       2.3660254037844384`, 0}}], 
    Polygon[{{4.598076211353316`, 2.3660254037844384`, 
       0}, {4.098076211353316`, 1.5`, 0}, {4.964101615137754`, 1.`, 
       0}, {5.464101615137754`, 1.8660254037844386`, 0}}], 
    Polygon[{{5.464101615137754`, 1.8660254037844386`, 
       0}, {4.964101615137754`, 1.`, 0}, {5.964101615137754`, 1.`, 
       0}}]}}], {a, 0, ArcCos[-(1/Sqrt[3])]}]
```

Comment: You should also specify the rotation axes, e.g. by using syntax like `Rotate[g,\[Theta],w,p]` or `Rotate[g,\[Theta],{u,v}] `.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher I'm sorry you could give me an example of using the two syntaxes, because I can't figure out how to rotate the axes I want. I'm sorry, but I'm a beginner of the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing a polyhedron from flat polygons](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199468/developing-a-polyhedron-from-flat-polygons)